# Get Project's Credentials using Jenkins API

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

I'm building a Jenkins plugin that one of the features is to commit and push some files generated during the build. I already have the code to commit and to push (using Git client from org.jenkinsci.plugins), however when I execute

```
PushCommand push = gitClient.push();
push.ref(__MY_BRANCH__);
push.to(new URIish("origin"))
push.force();
push.execute();
```

I get an error not having permissions to push. So, my question is: how can I re-use the credentials of a project to proper configue *gitClient* or the *pushCommand* ?

--
Thanks,
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide credentials to the `GitClient`.

For example, here you can see the Git plugin [calling](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/c8d05b9/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/AbstractGitSCMSource.java#L125) the [`GitClient#addDefaultCredentials()`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/3139a94/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/GitClient.java#L71-L78) method, using credentials obtained from `CredentialsMatchers`.

You mention you want to re-use the credentials from the same job so — assuming that the Git plugin has been configured with those credentials — your plugin should have access to the `AbstractBuild` where you can use something like `build.getProject().getScm()​.getUserRemoteConfigs().get(0)​.getCredentialsId` to fetch the configured credentials ID.

You'll need to cast the `SCM` to `GitSCM`, but otherwise that should work fine.

Comment: HI Christopher, many thanks for your help. just to complete your answer, after getting the credentialsId I'm creating a GitSCMSource and using it and the credentialsId to get an instance of StandardUsernameCredentials from CredentialsMatchers. then I'm just calling addDefaultCredentials() as you've suggested. and the push it's working. :)